# React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined (Arrow functions)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, setstate

I am not able to use setState. My code looks something like:

```
const FormComp = () => {
  const [reader, setReader] = React.useState(0);
//rest of the code
};

const Ques1 = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={() => {
                this.setState({ reader: "1" });
              }}>Click</button>
    </>
  )
};
```

This is just a short version of the code. I'm facing problem in this. Please someone help me out.
This code is in same file.
**UPDATE**:
tried `setReader` but it throws an error saying `setReader` is not defined

Comment: You are trying to modify the state of a functional component, the way you do in class component, thats not possible please read about Hooks on React documentation, "useState" hook specifically

Comment: What do you think `this` is, even? You have the correct thing, useState, in one component, why not do the same in the other?

Comment: When you define *reader* and *setReader*, you are pulling currentState and "futureState" (setter). You have to use *setReader* instead. Now `this.setState` is only when you are in a class based component.

Comment: @pensum if that's even accessible in Ques1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should use like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  const [reader, setReader] = React.useState(0);
  const FormComp = () => {
  //rest of the code
    return <div>Clicked {reader} times</div>
  };
  
  const Ques1 = () => {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => setReader(reader+1)}>Increase</button>
    )
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <FormComp />
      <Ques1 />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

You can set whatever value you want in setReader function.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `React.useState` you don't do `this.setState`, in this example you would just do:

```
 <button onClick={() => {
     setReader("1");
 }}>Click</button>
```

Comment: it is throwing error saying "setReader" is not defined

Comment: Ah just saw they are different components, you need to pass in `setReader` as a prop to `Ques1` - `const Ques1 = ({setReader}) => {` and then in `FormComp` it would be `<Ques1 setReader={setReader} />`

Answer (score 0):

since you're using the useState hook, you should call `setReader` instead of `this.setState`.

Comment: it is throwing error saying "setReader" is not defined

Answer (score 0):

When you use react hooks and functional components, you can throw away (by moment) the concepts about this.setState

Instead to use `this.setState({ reader: "1" })` for  `const [reader, setReader] = React.useState(0);` useState Hook. You should use `setReader(1)` or `setReader("1")` (According to your old "`this.setState({reader: "1"})`")

Button onClick be like:

```
<button onClick={() => setReader(1)}>
  Click
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues in your code.

1. You're using `setState` while using react hook `useState`
2. `useState` in being used in one component, trying to access it on another component

So, decide where do you need it, or you want to pass it as prop and/or [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)?

And use:

```
onClick={() => setReader(1)}
```